# Android Settings permissions not not acting as they should

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-permissions, android-settings

I need to ask for permission from the user. One of the permissions I need is `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` and the other is `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION`. When asking for it as you can see in the code below, it takes the user to the Settings screen so the user could tick the permission from there.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
        Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

On some Android phones and Android versions, it takes the user straight to the specific application setting (the app that it is called from) on other devices it opens up the list of applications from which the user has to find the app and then tick the permission. In most cases on Androids lower than 10 it opens up the specific app settings window and when it's 10 or higher, it opens up the list.
Is there a way to make it consistently open the current application setting that is open?

### I tried adding:

```
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
```

But that did not help either.

And secondly, is there a way to ask for this and other `Settings` permissions without opening the `Settings` menu and instead of doing it in a dialog inside the application? 
If not then is there a way to ask for multiple `Settings` permissions one after another because my application requires two `Settings` type permissions.

**EDIT**

Here is what I meant by the specific application settings vs the list.

[image: All application list][image: Specific app]

On the left picture, all apps are listed and on the right picture the specific app is opened (happens if you click on the app in the list).

Now in some cases, it directly opens the right picture but mostly it opens the left. Is there a way to force open the right picture at all times?

Comment: "Is there a way to make it consistently open the current application setting that is open?" -- what do you mean by "the current application setting that is open"? "is there a way to ask for this and other Settings permissions without opening the Settings menu and instead of doing it in a dialog inside the application? " -- no. "my application requires two Settings type permissions" -- perhaps you should reconsider your use of them. For example, system overlays are not available on some Android devices today, and I would not be surprised if they are blocked for all in the future.

Comment: @CommonsWare Edited the question to specify the "Is there a way to make it...". Thank you for the other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to force open the right picture at all times?

No.

The Settings app usually is modified substantially by the device manufacturer. They can do whatever they want. This includes ignoring the `Uri` or outright removing third-party access to this screen, where the latter is what [the documentation is warning against](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION):

> In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard against this.

If you make your own Android firmware, you could ensure that this `Intent` action behaves as you want, for whatever devices run your firmware.

Comment: As a follow up question if you know. Is it possible to somehow check if `Uri` is going to be ignored when this permission is asked or not. So if it is going to be ignored, I would first tell the user how to find the app and enable it.

Comment: @Richard: "Is it possible to somehow check if Uri is going to be ignored when this permission is asked or not" -- you would know if the `<intent-filter>` does not include the `package` scheme, as the `startActivity()` call would just fail to find a match. However, if the `<intent-filter>` advertises that it accepts the `Uri`, you have no way of knowing what the app does with that `Uri`, including ignoring it.